# Alerts are annoying

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I'm sorry if I'm the only one who thinks this, but I think the "alert bar" (or whatever it's called - the orange bar that has badge notifications, etc.) on the top of the website is really annoying, because it moves the content of the page up/down. I would much rather see a lower-corner alert (a good example of this is on http://thesixtyone.com)

I realize this is a preference thing, but just wanted to throw it out there to see if others agreed.

Comment: My alarm clock annoyed me, so i cut out the buzzer. It's much nicer now. But i'm always late for morning meetings.

Comment: At least it's better than a javscript alert(); box...

Comment: "I realize this is a preference thing..." Exactly.  Maybe it should be a checkbox on each user's preference page to show alerts or not?

Comment: That would work for me - It would be a cool feature. Not sure how difficult/time consuming it would be to add, but considering Joel and Jeff are trying to sell this as a platform, it's probably wise to add it now before some client demands it :)

Comment: Seriously, I don't want a reminder to vote on every freakin page I visit at SO.  I always vote when appropriate.  It's like getting a reminder to breathe (air) .

Answer (score 14):

Just click the X and get rid of it. Adding in an entire preference setting and the logic behind it just to save yourself a single click is pretty absurd.

Comment: I'd upvote you, but that takes a single click, which is just too hard.

Answer (score 10):

I imagine I would often miss a badge alert if it was off in a corner.  I don't see a real problem with it the way it is.

Answer (score 7):

I see no issue with the bar. It gets your attention like it was designed to do, and it is easy to dismiss.

Comment: I think "attention" here is the key -- You know it is there, so even if the content shifts, you can dismiss the box and move on with your work (or fun).

Answer (score 4):

There should be an option to disable alerts.  I browse from multiple PCs and have to kill the alert multiple times on each PC...for each new response I probably see (and need to close) the alert 4-5 times.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are right. I just click on it and it is gone. But putting it in a corner would be an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

When I click the [x] the bar disappears until I click onto a question. Then it appears again.

Comment: sounds like browser caching issue

Comment: Actually, it was user error. some fool (me) was using the back button interspersed with my usage. Whenever I hit 'back' the bar would appear again.

Comment: But using the back button is a valid way of navigating - I use it all the time. I've learnt to dismiss the notification and refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the space above the logo and the information bar (with your username) and having it smaller. So it doesn't move the content down (which i think is the worst thing it does)

Answer (score 1):

I like jQuery-Notice:

http://sandbox.timbenniks.com/projects/jquery-notice/

Answer (score 0):

Most of the notifications are now delivered to your GlobalInbox

[image: inbox]